# Git password issue?

Tags: git, github

I'm committing to a Git repo using the command line, upon entering my username and password, it tells me that the authentication failed.

I am 100% certain that I'm typing my details correctly and it is *my* repo that I'm committing to.

I have no idea what is going wrong, the only symbol I have in either my username or password is an `@`.

Any help?

Comment: connection failed, due to Network Timeout (Server is not listening to the port) or Connection Refused (port is blocked) ?

Comment: It says `fatal: Authentication failed`

Comment: Are you connecting via HTTPS or SSH? I have different passwords for my Github login and my SSH key, maybe you do too? If you're using SSH, have you tried the test step described here: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: Did you check for any case issue (lowercase/uppercase) in your name/password or repo url?

Comment: @VonC, I did, it's correct.

Comment: @DanielLee, I'm using HTTPS.

Comment: Does it work with another github repo (even a new empty one created just for test)?

Comment: @DanielLee, Yep, it worked for a different repo..

Comment: And you're connecting to the correct url something like: `https://yourusername@github.com/user/repo.git` and not `git@github.com:yourusername/repo.git`? You can check what the url for origin is with `git remote -v` Does fetch or pull work? Or is it only on push that it fails?

Comment: @DanielLee, I honestly don't know what I did wrong, but upon re-pulling the repo, everything is working now...

Answer (score 1):

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#My_username_contains_a_.27.40.27.2C_I_can.27t_clone_through_HTTP.2FHTTPS

Solution : URL-escape the '@' sign in your username, i.e. replace it with %40, like git clone

```
   https://user%40mail.com@gitserver.com/path/.
```

Comment: Would I need to do that for my password?

Comment: you may temporarily change your password and even username to to check is problem  in @ character.